# Converting SCALA === (triple equal) to Python for SPARK column

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a following code in Scala for Python conversion

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame, Dataset}

object SearchTermReader {

  def read(
    searchTermsInputTable: DataFrame,
    brand: String,
    posa: String,
    startDate: String,
    endDate: String
  ): Dataset[SearchTerm] = {

    import searchTermsInputTable.sparkSession.implicits._

    val conditionsNoEndDate = getConditions(brand, posa, startDate)
    val searchTermsNoEndDate = searchTermsInputTable
      .where(conditionsNoEndDate)
      .cache()

    searchTermsNoEndDate.count()

    val columnNames = SparkExtensions.getColumns[SearchTerm]

    searchTermsNoEndDate
      .filter(col("report_date").leq(lit(endDate)))
      .select(columnNames: _*)
      .as[SearchTerm]
  }

  def getConditions(
    brand: String,
    posa: String,
    startDate: String
  ): Column = {

    val filterByBrandCondition: Column = {
      if (brand.equals("")) {
        lit(true)
      } else {
        col("brand") === brand
      }
    }
    val filterByPosaCondition: Column = {
      if (posa.equals("")) {
        lit(true)
      } else {
        col("account_name").rlike(getAccountPattern(posa))
      }
    }

    filterByBrandCondition &&
      filterByPosaCondition &&
      col("search_engine") === "GOOGLE" &&
      col("impressions") > 0 &&
      col("report_date").geq(lit(startDate))
  }

  def getAccountPattern(countryCodes: String): String = {
    countryCodes.split(",").map(cc => s":G:$cc:").mkString("|")
  }
}
```

Seems to be two issues here for straight conversion.

1. Dataset is used which is not supported by Pyspark
2. === is used for Column which is also not supported

How I can overcome this and convert it to Python ??

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to column of the dataframe then you can use it like below.

```
df.filter((col("brand") == "BRAND") & (...))
```

Comment: its not dataframe, just Column type. Its imported like this: from pyspark.sql import Column. Scala allows for  === but not pyspark API, at least I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

Pyspark doesn't support using `===` just as `Scala`.

In Scala, the `==` is using the equals methods which checks if the two references point to the same object. The definition of `===` depends on the context/object. For Spark , `===` is using the `equalTo` method.

In Pyspark, you make use of `=` or `==`.
Having said that, in Pyspark you do following implementations to get same result per your `Scala` code -

```
df.filter("Brand = 'BRAND'")
```

Or,

```
df.filter(df.Brand == 'BRAND')
```

Or,

```
df.filter(df["Brand"] == 'BRAND')
```

Or,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.filter(col("Brand") == 'BRAND')
```

Comment: as above val expected: Column = is org.apache.spark.sql.Column object with no dataframe. I know that I can rewrite the code and put it to DataFrame than make new column there but it will require quite many changes.

Comment: Can you explain your exact use case ? Though I haven't worked much on `scala` `spark`.

Comment: just changed description to have better explanation of my case

Comment: I don't think those use cases are possible in Pyspark. Only one solution I can think , is of the route of `dataframe` if your end goal is just to create a `constant` with `val` keyword. Also, I'm just curious if your `Scala` code is working per your requirements, why do you want to migrate it to `Pyspark` for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation how to convert === in Scala to python for those
particular cases from above its enough to use == in Python

so

```
val filterByBrandCondition: Column = {
      if (brand.equals("")) {
        lit(true)
      } else {
        col("brand") === brand
      }
    }
```

converts to

```
if (brand == ""):
      filterByBrandCondition: Column = lit(True)
    else:
      filterByBrandCondition: Column = (col("brand") == brand)
```

and

```
col("search_engine") === "GOOGLE"
```

to

```
col("search_engine") == "GOOGLE"
```

Using of Dataset can be replaced by DataFrame. Variable

```
val columnNames = SparkExtensions.getColumns[SearchTerm]
```

needs to be replaced by code which will read column names from dataframe